# Mapping proportional Data for two group on single Map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, mapping

I have no experience in mapping but for my research purpose I required to map certain data on Map of certain country. Data is like this :

```
State     Proportion of X     Proportion of Y     Rest
A         50                  30                  20
B         79                  20                  1
C         95                  4                   1
.
.
.
```

Such that there are total 30 states and for each state I required to show proportion of X and Y on the same map for comparison purpose so that reader could understand the where proportion of X is high or low in contrast to Y. 
One of my friend told me about software ArcMap but another told me it is not possible to plot both the proportion on the same MAP. 
I have access to ArcMap or any other that would be recommended if it is open source. I have no prior knowledge in mapping in any software.

I want to know is it possible to show such data on MAP in the way what I want ? And which software is most appropriate for it [please be restricted to ArcMap or  open source software]

You may recommend me tutorial video for this purpose if providing entire solution is not possible.

I want something like this : 
[image]

Here is Zoom view

[image]

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are asking. Any chance of an image to illustrate.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  If you have access to ArcMap then I suspect what you are trying to do can be easily done but we need you to focus your question on that software using the [edit] button beneath it, and to provide the image that @JohnBarça has suggested.

Comment: @JohnBarça  I have uploaded the image. Here green colour is proportion of X, Red is proportion for Y.

Comment: I want overlapping of Red color on the green color for each states.

Comment: In your example for State A how are you planning to colour a 50:30:20 split?  I would suggest pie charts rather than colour ramping would be more appropriate.

Comment: @PolyGeo I want some kind of red color dot in green which is uniformly distributed over the entire state. I donot think pie chart is feasible here. There are total 30 states means 30 pie charts.

Comment: Can you include a zoomed in view of a couple of states showing how that map represents their data?  If you have something specific that you are trying to achieve then your question will fare better, but if you are just asking for ideas then it will be too broad for focussed Q&A.

Comment: @PolyGeo It is very specific question. I want to plot something in a new fashion. I just want to know is it possible or not ?

Comment: And please donot put this question on hold...

Comment: From the second picture it looks like every polygon is either a shade of green, or it is a shade of red.  Going back to your example for State A of a 50:30:20 split - how would you propose that this be shaded?

Comment: @PolyGeo I want something interesting. I donot know is it possible or not ? What I want both red and green in every polygon. Lets say, If second ratio is represented by Red, then I want red and green in such a way that every polygon 30 percent area filled with red, 50 percent with green and left with any other color(may be blue). It means there would be three color in each polygon. I want color to be uniformly distributed such that red appear in entire polygon with green shades.

Comment: @PolyGeo this is something which I did not find anywhere.

Comment: If you left the other category out then your Muslim:Christian ratio could be used to do a simple red to green colour ramp.

Comment: @PolyGeo Is it possible ?

Comment: @PolyGeo I have no problem in lefting other. Please suggest how it can be done ?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/157137/115 should lead you into the relevant technique of colour ramps and its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative approach to @PolyGeo's solution (Muslim:Christian ratio).

Use the number of people per state to calculate the number of Muslim and the number of Christian people per state.

With [ArcGIS (ArcMap) you can use dot densities](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_symbolizing_layers_to_represent_quantity/00s500000034000000/) to show the number of Muslim people (green dots) and Christian people (red dots). Each dot represents a certain number of people (for example, one dot for every 100,000).

(The of approach to use the Muslim:Christian ratio is generally good. The disadvantage of Muslim:Christian ratio is: a state with 7% Christians and 3% Muslims has the same color as a state with 70% / 30%. And I'm not sure if this message is desired in your map.)